# Is it possible to run scrypt hashing on the antminer S9 i just bought two to mine dogecoin?

Tags: dogecoin, antminer, scrypt

its the ANTMINERS9 mining hardware- ASIC power use 1600w processing speed 13500[GH/s] Hash Algorithm Script,X11,SHA-256, SHA-256D